# Reply to remote akka.net actor

Tags: akka.net

I have a SenderActor deployed to one machine and one ReceiverActor deployed on another machine (using Akka.Remote). The Sender succesfully initiates the call to the Receiver.

I'm trying to reply some status from the Receiver back to the sender but the Receiver can't find the Sender.

The Sender is configured like this:

```
deployment {
    /Rtpe {
       remote = "akka.tcp://TransactionImporterActorSystem@10.0.0.100:8091"
     }
   }
   remote {
     helios.tcp {
      transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
      transport-protocol = tcp
      port = 0
      hostname = "10.0.0.100"
}
```

And the Receiver like this:

```
remote {
    helios.tcp {
      transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
      transport-protocol = tcp
      port = 8091
      hostname = "10.0.0.100"
    }
}
```

The call is initiated with:

```
   var actorSelection = transactionActorSystem
                    .ActorSelection("/user/Rtpe/TransactionCoordinator");
```

How can I reply back to the remote actor?

Comment: Have you tried to send reply back by using `Sender.Tell(response)`?

Comment: yes, Sender.Tell() will try to send the messages to the local parent.

Comment: Sender.Tell should send the reply to an actor who send the message, you're currently handling.